# Generating n random numbers between i and j python

Tags: python, r, random

I want to create a random number using n numbers which are between i and j. For instance, for n=10 and i=1 and j=5, such an output is expected: `2414243211`. I did it in R using this code:

```
paste(floor(runif(10,1,5)),collapse="") #runif create 10 random number between 1 and 5 and floor make them as integer and finally paste makes them as a sequence of numbers instead of array.
```

I want to do the same in Python. I found `random.uniform` but it generates 1 number and I don't want to use loops.

```
import random
import math
math.floor(random.uniform(1,5)) #just generate 1 number between 1 and 5
```

**update**:

- i and j are integers between 0 and 9, while n could be any integer.
- i and j decide which number can be used in the string while n indicates the length of the numeric string.

Comment: In native Python you'll have to use a loop - if you're familiar with R - then you might want to look at numpy/pandas.

Comment: So you want one number with those digits?  `int(''.join([str(math.floor(random.uniform(1,5))) for _ in range(10)]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question (not sure I do), and you have Python 3.6, you can use `random.choices`:

```
>>> from random import choices
>>> int(''.join(map(str, choices(range(1, 5), k=10))))
2121233233
```

Answer (score 3):

If you consider list-comprehensions being loops (which they actually in many ways are) there you will not be satisfied with this but I will try my luck:

```
from random import randint

res = ''.join([str(randint(1, 5)) for _ in range(10)])
print(res)  #-> 4353344154
```

Notes:

1. The result is a string! If you want an integer, cast to `int`.
2. `randint` works *incluselively*; the `start` (`1`) and `end` (`5`) might be produced and returned. If you do not want that, modify them (`start = 2` and `end = 4`)
3. Is there a reason you are using `random.uniform` (and subsequently `math.floor()`) and not simply `randint`?

Comment: Since I want to create thousands of these numbers with different lengths, I prefer to use loops for that purpose and not for generating random numbers. So there is no way to generate more than 1 number without loops? For 3, no, I simply was not aware of `randint`. Thank you very much

Comment: @Hadij There is. just wrap the existing list-comprehension in another one. `res = [''.join([str(randint(1, 5)) for _ in range(10)]) for _ in range(5)]`

Answer (score 3):

The [*random.choices()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function does what you want:

```
>>> from random import choices
>>> n, i, j = 10, 1, 5
>>> population = list(map(str, range(i, j+1)))
>>> ''.join(choices(population, k=n))
'5143113531'
```

Comment: I'd go for: `''.join(map(str, choices(range(i, j+1), k=n)))` - no need to make the range a list, just let it sample from the range, and have that mapped. Might just be worth noting that `choices` is 3.6+ - still a lot of people on 3.5...

Comment: That's pretty much what I did @JonClements but Raymond is there a reason to do the string conversion *before sampling with choices?

Comment: Thinking about cases where `range(1, 1000000000)` could be the candidate pool and `k=10` is all that's required... at least you'll only have a list of 10 elements instead of a temporary one of the range...

Comment: @Chris_Rands oh - so you did - sorry I didn't see that while commenting on Raymond's answer...

Comment: It's hard to tell which is best from the question as worded.  My take was that *i* and *j* were digit ranges so there would be ten or fewer of them.  Meanwhile, it looked like *n* could get large.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Yes, You are right. i and j are in this range [0,9] and n could be any integer. thank you.

Comment: @Hadij  Given that interpretation, can you mark this as answer as the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = ''.join([str(math.floor(random.uniform(1,5)))  for i in range(10)])
```